# .htaccess not behaving as desired

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritecond

Eventhough I'm new at htaccess, I've been learning a lot in the past few days, but I'm stuck on a certain part that resulted in the website not behaving as desired. Here is the part of the code where I have my delima:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
Rewriterule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC]
# RewriteCond /templates/%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ index.php?$1 [NC,S=1]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ product.php?product_id=$1 [NC]
```

The first RewriteCond and RewriteRule works perfect. My problem with what goes afterwards.

What I need to achieve is that when a user inputs */some-word* it would search if a file with the same name is valid in the */templates* folder, and hence would serve it as *index.php?some-word*, else it would be served as *product.php?product_id=some-word*.
The the *index.php* rule works well when the second condition is commented out, but when added only the *product.php* rule works.

The supplied "tag" could be numbers, letters, hyphenated words (i.e. any-words), or a combination of numbers and letters. The rules should be case insensitive.

I appreciate any assistance on the matter.

Comment: You need a condition for the first and the second rules as well, otherwise only the last one will be applied.

Comment: Thanks Marcel, but that is what I did, the first condition worked with the first rule, but the second condition will not work with the second rule, for some reason. I might have done something wrong with the second condition, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is the *absolute* path translated from the URL, that is, for http://example.com/foobar it may be something like `/var/www/vhost/example.com/httpdocs/foobar` (depending on how your web server is setup).
I suggest you use pattern matching on the URL as in

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/templates/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([^\/\.]+)$ index.php?$1 [NC,S=1]
```

(I didn't test that though)

Comment: Thanks Hagen, that was perfect, worked like a charm. I know it was something with my second condition. Again, thank you.